# How can I convert a View to a Drawable?

Tags: android

I have a `View` and I want to convert it into an image in order to store it somewhere.
But how can I convert this `View` to an image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this for take image of view and store in sd card..

```
View view = TextView.getRootView();
//You can use any view of your View instead of TextView

if (view != null)
{
    System.out.println("view is not null.....");
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();

    try
    {
        if (bm != null)
        {
            String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            System.out.println("bm is not null.....");
            OutputStream fos = null;
            File file = new File(dir,"sample.JPEG");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error="+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Enable drawing cache on the view:

   ```
   view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   ```
2. Create a bitmap from the cache:

   ```
   bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
   ```
3. Save the bitmap wherever...
4. Disable drawing cache:

   ```
   view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
   ```

Comment: I'm getting a **NullPointerException** for this code line `Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());` What can be the reason ?