# How to convert linearlayout to image

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I want to convert the full `layout` with it's contents (`views`) into Drawable image?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776684/how-can-i-convert-a-view-to-a-drawable

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the following code:

---

```
public class AndroidWebImage extends Activity {

ImageView bmImage; 
LinearLayout view;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen);
      bmImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

      view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      // this is the important code :)  
      // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null          

      view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

      view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight()); 

      view.buildDrawingCache(true);
      Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
      view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache

      bmImage.setImageBitmap(b);   

};


}
```

---

Take a good look, you have to use:

```
 view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

 view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
```

---

I used the following **main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/screen"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
<TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/hello"
  />
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### The outcome is:

[image]
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339429/android-view-getdrawingcache-returns-null-only-null)

Comment: you saved me buddy