# Android Screen Recorder

Tags: android

I'm trying to record android screenshots when I'm drawing something on the screen and after generate a video. I'm thought to do this with a "for" looping but I had problems when I called the getDrawingCache() method. In principle it works right, but if I change something on screen when the "drawing cache" is called, the android app is closed without error reported. Below is my source code.

```
public void run() {
        Bitmap screenshot;
        File file;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

        this.view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        for (long i = 1; record; i++) {

            screenshot = (Bitmap) Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());

            file = new File(directory, "frm" + i + ".jpg");

            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                screenshot.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, fileOutputStream);

                fileOutputStream.close();
                ScreenshotRecorder.sleep(50);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        this.view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    }
```

I've looked for another way to get android screen recorder, but I've not found open source apps. If someone know some way how to get android screen capture, I'm grateful. Thanks for all.

(I'm using a Xoom Tablet and android 3.0 version)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call `view.buildDrawingCache(...)` before you call get drawing cache, or there will be nothing to get. You can read about this [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#buildDrawingCache%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I already had tried it before and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
view.buildDrawingCache(true);
```

From my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674570/how-to-convert-linearlayout-to-image/10675244#10675244) to avoid **null** image

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't works. I try it into the for block, but the app is closed without no erro reported. Do you know some app to take screen recorder on android Xoom not rooting?