# How to save my UI or layout Screen as image with high resolution in android

Tags: android-imageview

I want to do image masking in android and want to save the masked image with  a higher resolution. 
I am new to android so please I would appreciate if I can have a detailed procedure.

Comment: stackoverflow

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674570/how-to-convert-linearlayout-to-image

may be this can help you

Comment: I have tried this solution and it works fine to save a layout as image.I Want to set the image resolution before saving the image, how can i set it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can covert bitmap in .png file and save it to phone memory/SD card.
Let you have HDPI phone 480*800 you can not save image(Layout) higher than 480*800 without loosing its quality.
You can change size(scaling) let 1200*1600 but you will lose quality.
You can not increase resolution. However you can decrease it.