# How to combine TextView and an image and return an image?

Tags: android, android-canvas

While searching for results I came across this
[How can I convert a View to a Drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776684/how-can-i-convert-a-view-to-a-drawable)
The idea behind this is I can convert `TextView` into a bitmap first and then combine the two bitmaps. But by converting the `TextView` into Bitmap, it would make it lose it's transparency which I don't want. I want the `TextView` over my `ImageView` but as one image using canvas.

My idea is to create images like these:

[image]

Here I want to enclose the text with a drawable shape for that white border.
And then place this `Textview` on an image and then save everything as a bitmap.
Please help

Comment: Do you need the user to do it? or do you need to do it to implement the image in you app?

Comment: @Daniele I want to do it in the app but the end result should be an image and not layers of views if that's what else you wanted to know

Comment: Make a custom Drawable.  Drawable will allow you to render text, bitmaps, and shapes to a Canvas object to do what you want.  You also have complete control over the transparency this way as well.

Comment: @MichaelKrause the method in that link returns a bitmap, can u give me some sample code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to draw text and lines on canvas.
Below is example method which draws text on drawable image and returns `Bitmap`.
You can set custom font by calling `.setTypeface()` on `Paint` object.
Call `canvas.drawLine()` to draw line. To customize your line you can create new `Paint` object, set its color and width by `.setColor()` and `.setStrokeWidth()` and pass it in `drawLine()` together with line coordinates.

```
public Bitmap drawTextOnBitmap(Context context, int resId, String text) {

        // prepare canvas
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resId);

        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
        // set default bitmap config if none
        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        // resource bitmaps are immutable, so we need to convert it to mutable one
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        // new antialiased Paint
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        // text color - #3D3D3D
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(61, 61, 61));
        // text size in pixels
        paint.setTextSize((int) (bitmap.getHeight() / 10 * scale));
        // text shadow
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

        // set text width to canvas width minus 16dp padding
        int textWidth = canvas.getWidth() - (int) (16 * scale);

        // init StaticLayout for text
        StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, textWidth,
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

        // get height of multiline text
        int textHeight = textLayout.getHeight();

        // get position of text's top left corner
        float x = (bitmap.getWidth() - textWidth) / 2;
        float y = (bitmap.getHeight() - textHeight) / 2;

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(x, y);
        textLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        return bitmap;
    }
```

**Update:**
To draw rectangle add this to the method:

```
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(24);
        RectF rectF = new RectF(80, 150, 200, 350);
        canvas.drawRect(rectF, p);
```

Parameters for new RectF():
**left**
The X coordinate of the left side of the rectangle
**top**
The Y coordinate of the top of the rectangle
**right**
The X coordinate of the right side of the rectangle
**bottom**
The Y coordinate of the bottom of the rectangle

Comment: Can you help me with the co ordinates for canvas.drawRect()?
Whatever i am trying with your above method doesnt seem to be working

Comment: but these are static points, i couldn't put them around the text.

Comment: so i am using a different view now but then by using this view, i am unable to put this view in the centre of the canvas.

Comment: would u like to see it's code?i guess it is easier to fix that

Comment: well never-mind i was having a problem with width earlier, now i updated ur answer

Comment: @dzikovskyy , in `// text size in pixels ==>
        paint.setTextSize((int) (bitmap.getHeight() / 10 * scale));` , how can I change text size ???