# What does it mean to convert a layout to image in android

Tags: android

I came across the following  - [How to convert linearlayout to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674570/how-to-convert-linearlayout-to-image) .
It converts a linear layout to an image. What is it exactly doing?
Is it like I press a button and it saves the screenshot of the app screen as an Image?
Is that what is meant by converting a LinearLayout to Image?

Comment: that question has a link to a potential duplicate. clicking that link shows an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776741/4729721) which explains exactly what it's doing (creating a jpeg of the view) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776684/how-can-i-convert-a-view-to-a-drawable

Answer (score 0):

I think Android already convert view to Bitmap for show on screen. You can call view.getDrawingCache() and you can set on your imageview with bitmap.

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());

bmImage.setImageBitmap(b);